# Python function to get log2 transformation of each row?

Tags: python, function, pandas

I  have a dataframe ,df as mentioned below. It has 1 object columns (Genes) and 7 Float columns( Grow1,Grow2,Grow3,NoGrow1,NoGrow1,Nogrow3 and Mean).

The columns values are FPKM ( gene expression values) of different genes under Grow and Nogrow conditions in triplicates.

I wanted to create a new data frame df1 from df. In new data frame every value has to be  log2 normalized to Mean. Mean column is mean of all the values in the row.

In excel:

i do this:     LOG((C3+0.1)/(I+0.1),2) to get  new value for Grow1/RMRP and drag the across the column and row  to create the normalized values for whole dataframe.

key:

C3= 6.059720  I=7.652560 .  I add 0.1 to both values to take care of "0 " values in the columns.

In Pandas:

I created the lambda function. as shown below, func2. but when i apply it i cannot get it work. i tried many ways but it was frustrating. [please refer the link image for my dataframe, df and functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcytB.png)

or is there any normal function can do log2 transformation?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df1 = df.add(.1)
df1 = np.log2(df1.drop('Mean', 1).div(df1.Mean, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.